# SplitInstallManager.startConfirmationDialogForResult calls deprecated onActivityResult (Dynamic feature modules)

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I'm using Dynamic feature modules in my app.

`onActivityResult` is deprecated. However, `SplitInstallManager.startConfirmationDialogForResult` uses the `onActivityResult` callback. Is there a way around this?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startConfirmationDialogForResult(com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallSessionState,%20android.app.Activity,%20int)

Comment: The link is wrong btw